# send async with slow consumer

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

In a non-blocking socket mode when a server sent data synchronously, if a client processed tcp buffer slower than the sender, `send()` will begin to block/timeout.

Is it the case when server send the data asynchronously ? (for instance with boost asio method `async_send`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The async operations will take longer to complete.

No, the code invoking the asynchronous operations doesn't block (that's what *asynchronous* means).

`send` is usually synchronous, `async_send` never is. Of course, if you wait for all asynchronous operations to complete, you end up with the same delay, but that's your choice.

Comment: "the async operation will take longer to complete", does it mean that with the async fashion I introduce some latency (compared to the sync way) ?

Comment: No. Latency is introduced in the lower ISO levels or in the client, as always